# Why do I get a black/purple screen when booting on a brand new PC build?

Tags: boot, system-installation, ati

So I am quite new to Linux/Ubuntu, and while searching for parts and building my new PC myself, i decided i wanted to cut some costs by installing Linux instead of Windows. I have the PC all put together, everything runs fine and i can boot up to the BIOS menu easily. I have downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS onto my USB flash drive using pendrivelinux.com and have attempted to boot up and install Linux multiple times. But everytime I try to install Linux or try Linux without installing, the monitor shows a loading screen and then goes to a purple screen (or a black screen when I use my TV as a monitor). The onboard video is already disabled to my knowledge. I do not have any other operating system installed on my build and am trying to make Ubuntu the native OS.

My build includes:

- MSI 970A-G43 ATX AM3+ Motherboard
- AMD FX-6300 3.5GHz 6-Core Processor
- G.Skill Ripjaws X Series 8GB (2 x 4GB) DDR3-1600 Memory
- Western Digital Caviar Blue 1TB 3.5" 7200RPM Internal Hard Drive
- MSI R9 270X Gaming 4G
- NZXT Source 210 Elite (White) ATX Mid Tower Case
- Corsair CX 500W 80+ Bronze Certified Semi-Modular ATX Power Supply

Answer (score 2):

After playing and searching around, I found that I could enter the GRUB menu by holding down F11, then pressing "e" on "install ubuntu" i then looked for where it said "quick splash --" and changed it to "nomodeset $vt_handoff" this allowed my system to boot it all up and after installing I played around with the /etc/default/grub file and changed around some text to allow my system to boot up  right to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to your graphics card not being compatible with Ubuntu right out of the box.  Try removing your graphics card and running on off the integrated graphics to see if that’s the problem.  Also make sure your usb drive is prepared with AMD64 Ubuntu not Intel x86 Ubuntu.

The problem is that you would need to have some sort of display port on your mobo to install Ubuntu with integrated graphics, then fix the problem with graphics card. Many people online have the same problem as you have, but they have installed Ubuntu on the without the graphics card. Just look up 270x in ubuntu and see what you get. This sounds very frustrating and hope it's resolved soon.

Comment: Thank you for responding, i have seen multiple people say the same thing you have, unfortunately, i believe the only way i can route video to my monitor is via the hdmi/vga ports, which only appear on my video card, not on the actual motherboard itself, so no video card, no hdmi/bga, i think. is there any way around this?

Comment: The problem is that you would need to have some sort of display port on your mobo to install Ubuntu with integrated graphics, then fix the problem with graphics card. Many people online have the same problem as you have, but they have installed Ubuntu on the without the graphics card. Just look up 270x in ubuntu and see what you get. This sounds very frustrating and hope it's resolved soon.

Comment: If you are feeling comfortable enough you could try this:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11586016.   Even though it's for an nVidia graphics card.

Comment: After tinkering with it all night, I found that changing quick splash to nomodeset solved all my problems, thanks for all your help!

Comment: Great to hear that! Make your own answer and accept it so other people with the same problem can see the solution.