# Graphic card Nvidia gtx 745 and intel D graphics 4400

Tags: drivers, nvidia, dvi

Hi all I'm having some issues with trying to install Ubuntu. For the past day's when I get to the boot menu I select my usb key which I turned into a bootable Ubuntu drive. When I click try or install Ubuntu I get a black screen and nothing happens. My screen is connected through DVI on my tower and HDMI on my screen. My question is how can I install Ubuntu since I can't see anything?

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this thread:
 [Why do I get a black/purple screen when booting on a brand new PC build?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562293/why-do-i-get-a-black-purple-screen-when-booting-on-a-brand-new-pc-build/562303#562303)

This is what solved the persons problem:

"After playing and searching around, I found that I could enter the GRUB menu by holding down F11, then pressing "e" on "install ubuntu" i then looked for where it said "quick splash --" and changed it to "nomodeset $vt_handoff" this allowed my system to boot it all up and after installing I played around with the /etc/default/grub file and changed around some text to allow my system to boot up right to Ubuntu."

You could also try this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11586016

Comment: Also, try turning off integrated graphics if you have them on.

Comment: ok ive tried what you said it worked i was able to install ubuntu but now after click ubuntu on grub i get a black screen i have to go in recovery mode and start with resume normal boot thats my only was to get in ubuntu also i dont see my graphic card ive tried to install it but doesnt work

Comment: Which way worked?  Also, what version of Ubuntu did you install?

Comment: im installing 14.04 ive removed quick splash and replace it with nomodeset after that i was able to install but now i cant log into ubuntu unless i go trought recovery mode

Comment: Ok, try removing your graphics card to see if that's the problem.  Try to boot without your graphics card installed.

Comment: ive trying it and nothing happens i still cant load into ubuntu

Comment: ok i have try with removing quie splash with the 'e'e in grub and put nomodeset it worked it load up ubuntu but no graphic card driver

Comment: Ok, try the link put in the bottom of my answer. Its for Nvidia graphics, see if that might work. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11586016

Comment: ok i did but now i after i enter my password nothing happen im staying at the loading to get in

Comment: yeah i can enter trought recovery mode  :(

Comment: Try going back to quick splash and then do the link. I really don't know now how to resolve this problem. Hopefully someone with more experience will come and help you.  Thanks for your time.